Issues with mobx global states after deploying with heroku
I'm working on a React webapp and using mobx (v6) + mobx-react (v9) for global state management. I'm maintaining a couple of values across pages with a store and everything works as expected when I run it locally.
However, I've successfully deployed my app on Heroku and it seems that the displayed values are reverting back to their default values when I navigate between pages on the deployed site.
Has anyone encountered this, worked with mobx + heroku before, or know any alternatives for global state that definitely work? I don't to refactor, deploy, then have it not work again. Other packages used btw: react-dom, trpc, Next
Here's how I'm setting up my mobx store:
import { makeAutoObservable } from "mobx";

class _SearchStore {
  amount = "500";

  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this);
  }
  public setAmount = (amount: string) => {
    this.amount = amount;
  }
}

export const SearchStore = new _SearchStore();

I set up a RootStore:
import { createContext, ReactNode, useContext } from "react";

const RootStore = {
  SearchStore,
};

export const StoreContext = createContext(RootStore);

export const useStores = () => {
  return useContext(StoreContext);
};

export const StoreProvider = ({
  children,
}: {
  children: ReactNode;
}) => {
  return (
    <StoreContext.Provider value={RootStore}>
      {children}
    </StoreContext.Provider>
  );
};

and using it in my app like this:
import { observer } from "mobx-react";

const Homepage = observer(() => {
   const { SearchStore } = useStores();

   ...
   
   <input
     type="number"
     value={SearchStore.amount}
     onChange={(e) => SearchStore.setAmount(e.target.value)}
   />
    
}

